# GDB set substitute-path not working

Tags: gdb

I have an executable that was built with `g++ -O0 -g` (GCC 4.3.4) and immediately the source code was archived.  At a later time it was altered.  I now want to debug the original version.  The executable saved the location of the original source code, which right now is populated by a different version with the same file names.  I want to point GDB (GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (7.5.1-0.7.29)) to the old source code.  I have extracted it to a new location.  I have tried setting the directory and substitute-path.  Each time the loaded source code is the modified version.  The commands I'm using are:

```
set directories /.../PILAGER2/unzip/source/
set substitute-path /.../PILAGER2/source/ /.../PILAGER2/unzip/source/
```

I have replaced the bulk of the path with /.../.

However if I type `info source` when the break point is reached the wrong file is shown.  If I delete the files from the original location the correct ones are used.  How do I properly tell GDB to use the source files from the unzipped location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the disk system was on a separate server.  Using the path supplied by the administrators was actually a link to a location on a parallel fileshare.  Using the actual path on the Panasas system worked.  In my case that means the path started with `/panfs/` followed by the server instead of `/project/...`